# Forward requests from example.com:8000 (old REST API) to api.example.com (new REST API) on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I have this problem and I am a bit confused on where to start. I have a Django REST API currently running on a VPS (with apache) and start with djangos `runserver` command (I know, I know, not the best way) so it is currently accessed via `http://example.com:8000/api`.

I am now moving to AWS and using Elastic Beanstalk to run my newly created Django REST API. I want to keep the domain something like `example.com/api` or `api.example.com`. Now this should be fine for me to set up but the problem I now have is I want to forward all old requests using the old API to the new API. What is the best way to do this?

Any help will be appreciated! :)

Comment: It's important to know that if your API uses `POST` then it may or may not be properly supported with a redirect.  See [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect) for many more details.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

- Rewrite
- Redirect

**Rewrite:**

With rewrite you read the contents using the old api and serve on the same request.

**Redirect:**

With redirect you send a 302 with the redirect location to your new API url.

Any request to  http://example.com:8000/api/something  will be responded with a http status code 302 and location as  http://example.com/api/something or http://api.example.com/something

If you do not wish you to use the old API, then it is better to redirect to the new destination.

If changing the URL on the client side is possible, then you can abondon mantaining the old endpoint or any of these process.

Hope it helps.